# if or try loop for an element in a page selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape agents data here. I am able to get the links from the first page. I am using numbered loops because I know the total number of pages. I tried to run this as long as the "next" page option is there. I tried both "try" and "if not" but wasn't able to figure it out. Any help is welcome. Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/../Downloads/cd79/chromedriver.exe', options=options)


links_total = []
driver.get("https://www.cbp.gov/contact/find-broker-by-port?field_port_location_tid=All&field_port_code_value=")
def first_links():
    initial_data = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for initial in initial_data:
        page_links = initial.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for page in page_links:
            page_link = page.get_attribute("href")
            links_total.append(page_link)
    driver.refresh()
    if driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('next'):
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('next')
        next_page.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        new_data = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        for new in new_data:
            links = new.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
            for link in links:
                new_link = link.get_attribute("href")
                links_total.append(new_link)



for i in range(1, 23):
    first_links()


for link in links_total:
    print(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try-catch would be better option

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/../Downloads/cd79/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# links_total = []
driver.get("https://www.cbp.gov/contact/find-broker-by-port?field_port_location_tid=All&field_port_code_value=")

def first_links(links_total=[]):
    initial_data = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for initial in initial_data:
        page_links = initial.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for page in page_links:
            page_link = page.get_attribute("href")
            links_total.append(page_link)
    # driver.refresh()
    try:
      next_page = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('next')
      next_page.click()
      time.sleep(2)
      first_links(links_total) 
    except (TimeoutError, ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
      print("NEXT btn not found : ")
      pass

    return links_total

all_links = first_links()

for link in all_links:
    print(link)
```

You don't need to use Selenium actually. You could do it with BeautifulSoap like so :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_num=0
url_cbp = r"https://www.cbp.gov/contact/find-broker-by-port?field_port_location_tid=All&field_port_code_value=&page={}"

def get_links(links_total=[], page_num=0):
  page = requests.get(url_cbp.format(page_num))
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  results = soup.find(id='region-content')

  table_cells = results.find_all('td', class_='views-field')
  for cell in table_cells:
    # print(cell )
    # print('\n\n')
    cell_link = cell.find('a')
    page_link = cell_link["href"]
    links_total.append(page_link)

  next_page = results.find('li', class_='pager-next')

  if next_page:
    page_num += 1
    get_links(links_total, page_num)

  return links_total

all_links = get_links()

for link in all_links:
  print(link)
```

Comment: ..The problem with this is..it only runs for the next page(i.e 1st page and 2nd page). I am not able to put the try catch in a loop where it keeps clicking the next page until there is no next element.

Comment: the cocde clock what is inside this `try` is what you want to execute in a loop?

Comment: as you can see..This will check for the next page only once. It cannot go back or click on the next page. That is the issue. Just have a short look at the webpage. After getting these links..there is another set of links with varying number of pages..So, the scraper must RETURN back as well if the "next " option does not exist. Otherwise, It will just end after links embedded in the 1st link end. It needs to come back and do the same for the next link in the series.

Comment: i have updated the code . you can try using this recursion approach .

Comment: I guess you didn't run it. This again will not return. This simply ends when there is no "next" option. Error with the code " raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"next"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=81.0.4044.138)"..This is slightly more complicated than it might appear. :)

Comment: my bad. where i have put `TimeoutError `, you have to include `NoSuchElementException` aswell

Comment: i ran it now . did you observe that there is a popup that will come n block the UI after 3 or 4 pages . you need to handle that . i'll try it out n tell you if it works

Comment: i dint get the popup now . in the above code change the line of except to : `except (TimeoutError, ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException) :`   .i'm getting all links now .

Comment: I tried this code already, for now it gives this error. Message: element click intercepted: Element <a title="Go to next page" href="/contact/find-broker-by-port?field_port_location_ti
d=All&amp;field_port_code_value=&amp;page=4" class="survey-processed">...</a> is not clickable at point (376, 581). Other element would receive the click: <div id="cboxOverlay" style="opaci
ty: 0.9; cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"></div> ...No, I didn't come across any pop-up issues. The code I have posted works perfectly. I will try running yours again and see

Comment: actually if this is all is the task , i mean if you wont get any more enhancements to this , it can be done easily with BeautifulSoup . I will show the code how it can be done.

Comment: This is not all the task. This is the list of first links. Then I need to click to each link..which will give a list of another links..page wise...then I need to click those one by one..then copy the data each shows to a csv file. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214805/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-sowjanya-r-bhat).