# Unable to parse the links of different cases from next pages using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've created a script to parse the links of different cases revealed upon selecting an option in dropdown from a webpage. This is the [website link](http://surrogateweb.co.ocean.nj.us/BluestoneWeb/Default.aspx) and this is the option `Probate` that should be chosen from the dropdown titled as `Case Type` located at the top right before hitting the search button.  All the other options should be as they are.

`The script can parse the links of different cases from the first page flawlessly. However, I can't make the script go on to the next pages to collect links from there as well.`

This is how next pages are visible in there at the bottom:
[image]

And the dropdown should look when the option is chosen:
[image]

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "http://surrogateweb.co.ocean.nj.us/BluestoneWeb/Default.aspx"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name],select')}
    for k,v in payload.items():
        if k.endswith('ComboBox_case_type'):
            payload[k] = "Probate"
        elif k.endswith('ComboBox_case_type_VI'):
            payload[k] = "WILL"
        elif k.endswith('ComboBox_case_type$DDD$L'):
            payload[k] = "WILL"
        elif k.endswith('ComboBox_town$DDD$L'):
            payload[k] = "%"

    r = s.post(link,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for pk_id in soup.select("a.dxeHyperlink_Youthful[href*='Q_PK_ID']"):
        print(pk_id.get("href"))
```

***How can I collect the links of different cases from next pages using requests?***

PS I'm not after any selenium related solution.

Comment: see if you can get some idea from this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057796/6490744  . First code block is with `selenium` , you dont need that. check the second code block for `beautifulsoup` implementation , you might be able to solve.

Comment: I would surely use similar logic if there were any link connected to next pages. The logic of going on to the next page will be different here. Thanks @Sowjanya R Bhat.

Comment: What's your purpose?Do you want to get all the datas or just want to scrape them?Why don't export them all directly?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA he probably wants to get the case PK id and pull the web case details from this url `http://surrogateweb.co.ocean.nj.us/BluestoneWeb/WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=`. The csv only provides high level data. @robots.txt it can be done.

Comment: Sorry @fcsr, you are wrong. The data of that site are useless to me. However, it seemed challenging to me to scrape the content using requests from next pages and that is the reason I'm after it. Given that I'm only after the links.

Comment: Ah cool. If you just want the challenge. Inspect the request, reponse pattern. From the reponse you can figure out the required form data to send to get the next page. The are payload values you are a missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly examine the **network requests** in Dev Tools (*press F12 in Chromes*) and monitor the payload. There are bits of data that are missing in your request.

The reason for the missing form data is because it is added by JavaScript (when the user clicks on the page number). Once the form data has been set, there is JavaScript that executes the following:

```
xmlRequest.open("POST", action, true);
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
xmlRequest.send(postData);
```

So all you need to do is emulate that in your Python script. Although it looks like the paging functionality only requires two additional values `__CALLBACKID` and `__CALLBACKPARAM`

In the following example; I've scraped the first 4 pages (note: the first post is just the landing page):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = "http://surrogateweb.co.ocean.nj.us/BluestoneWeb/Default.aspx"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    r.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name],select')}
    for k,v in payload.items():
        if k.endswith('ComboBox_case_type'):
            payload[k] = "Probate"
        elif k.endswith('ComboBox_case_type_VI'):
            payload[k] = "WILL"
        elif k.endswith('ComboBox_case_type$DDD$L'):
            payload[k] = "WILL"
        elif k.endswith('ComboBox_town$DDD$L'):
            payload[k] = "%"

    page_id_list = ['PN0','PN1', 'PN2', 'PN3'] # TODO: This is proof of concept. You need to refactor code. Purhaps scrape the page id from paging html.

    for page_id in page_id_list:
        # Add 2 post items. This is required for ASP.NET Gridview AJAX postback event.          
        payload['__CALLBACKID'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ASPxGridView_search',
        # TODO: you might want to examine "__CALLBACKPARAM" acrross multiple pages. However it looks like it works by swapping PageID (e.g PN1, PN2)
        payload['__CALLBACKPARAM'] = 'c0:KV|151;["5798534","5798533","5798532","5798531","5798529","5798519","5798518","5798517","5798515","5798514","5798512","5798503","5798501","5798496","5798495"];CR|2;{};GB|20;12|PAGERONCLICK3|' + page_id + ';'
        
        r = s.post(link, data=payload)
        r.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        for pk_id in soup.select("a.dxeHyperlink_Youthful[href*='Q_PK_ID']"):
            print(pk_id.get("href"))
```

**Output**:

```
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798668
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798588
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798584
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798573
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798572
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798570
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798569
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798568
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798566
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798564
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798560
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798552
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798542
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798541
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798535
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798534
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798533
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798532
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798531
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798529
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798519
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798518
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798517
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798515
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798514
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798512
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798503
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798501
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798496
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798495
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798494
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798492
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798485
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798480
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798479
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798476
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798475
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798474
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798472
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798471
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798470
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798469
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798466
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798463
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798462
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798460
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798459
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798458
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798457
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798455
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798454
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798453
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798452
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798449
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798448
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798447
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798446
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798445
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798444
WebPages/web_case_detail_ocean.aspx?Q_PK_ID=5798443
```

*Whilst the solution can be achieved using **Requests**. It can be temperamental. **Selenium** is usually a better approach.*

Comment: A quick little question: how did you figure out that `PBN` in `__CALLBACKPARAM` should be replaced with the ids from `page_id_list`? Thanks.

Comment: If you inspect the paging button, they have a JavaSript click call e.g: onclick="ASPx.GVPagerOnClick('ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxGridView_search','PN2');". Afterwards I inspected the payload to see if the following is sent: ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxGridView_search and  PN2

Comment: That's the key pointer. I always tried with the right arrow key which stays the same `ASPx.GVPagerOnClick('ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxGridView_search','PBN');` no matter which page I tried to go on to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This codes works but use selenium instead of requests.

You need to install [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) python lib and download [gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). If you do not want to have geckodriver in c:/program you have to change **executable_path=** to the path you have geckodriver in. You maybe want to make the sleep time shorter to, but the site is loading so slow (for me) so i have to set long sleep times so the site loads correctly before trying to read from it.

```
from selenium import  webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

link = "http://surrogateweb.co.ocean.nj.us/BluestoneWeb/Default.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(link)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxSplitter1_ASPxComboBox_case_type_B-1')
dropdown.click()
time.sleep(0.5)
cases = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.dxeListBoxItem_Youthful')
for case in cases:
    if case.text == 'Probate':
        time.sleep(5)
        case.click()
        time.sleep(5)
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxSplitter1_ASPxButton_search')
search.click()
while True:
    time.sleep(15)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    for pk_id in soup.select("a.dxeHyperlink_Youthful[href*='Q_PK_ID']"):
        print(pk_id.get("href"))
    next = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.dxWeb_pNext_Youthful')
    if len(next) > 0:
        next[0].click()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I can see i have got a down vote. But this is the only solution that works as i know of..

Comment: But OP has announced that he didn't look forward to a solution with `selenium`.I didn't downvote your post, though.

Comment: So it can be handled easily,you could just delete it directly, or post a answer with `requests`.Just my suggestions.

Comment: But requests library can't do it so it is hard to do a version that will help someone

Comment: Please don't blame wantonly by saying that OP has downvoted your post. I know you had to spare substantial amount of time to come up with this solution, so it would be unjust if I did that. I added `PS` portion to make sure you or any other visitor understand I'm not after any selenium oriented solution @UWTD TV. Thanks.

Comment: Ok sorry but thought it was you when I got a down vote and your question changed.. I'm sorry to say but requests can't make it..

Comment: You are definitely wrong on this. Requests can surely make it. As a test you can use the value of this two keys within payload`ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ASPxGridView_search`,`__CALLBACKID` from any random page and run the script, you should get results from that particular page @UWTD TV.

Comment: Yes but it is the change page thing that requests gets stuck on @robot.txt

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use PBN to paginate through all the results. The key thing you need to do pass the callback state.

```
import html

import requests
import lxml.html
import demjson
import html


def paginate(url, callback_id):
        
    response = requests.get(url)

    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)

    yield tree

    # The first page of results is embedded in the full html
    # page. Subsequent pages of results will be extract from
    # partial html returned from an endpoint intended for AJAX

    # Set up the pagination payload with it's constant values
    payload = {}
    payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = None
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = None
    payload['__VIEWSTATE'], = tree.xpath(
        "//input[@name='__VIEWSTATE']/@value")
    payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'], = tree.xpath(
        "//input[@name='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value")
    payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'], = tree.xpath(
        "//input[@name='__EVENTVALIDATION']/@value")
    payload['__CALLBACKID'] = callback_id

    # To get the next page of results from the AJAX endpoint,
    # it's basically a post request with a 'PBN' argument. But,
    # we also have to pass around the callback state that 
    # the endpoint expects
    event_callback_source, = tree.xpath('''//script[contains(text(), "var dxo = new ASPxClientGridView('{}');")]/text()'''.format(callback_id.replace('$', '_')))
        
    callback_state = demjson.decode(re.search(r'^dxo\.stateObject = \((?P<body>.*)\);$', event_callback_source, re.MULTILINE).group('body'))

    # You may wonder why we are encoding the callback_state back to a string
    # right after we decoded it from a string.
    #
    # The reasons is that the original string uses single quotes and is
    # not html-escaped, and we need to use double quotes and html escape.
    payload[callback_id] = html.escape(demjson.encode(callback_state))

    item_keys = callback_state['keys']
    payload['__CALLBACKPARAM'] = 'c0:KV|61;{};GB|20;12|PAGERONCLICK3|PBN;'.format(demjson.encode(item_keys))

    # We'll break when we attempt to paginate to a next
    # page but we get the same keys
    previous_item_keys = None
        
    while item_keys != previous_item_keys:

        response = requests.post(url, payload)
        previous_item_keys = item_keys

        data_str = re.match(r'.*?/\*DX\*/\((?P<body>.*)\)', response.text)\
                     .group('body')

        data = demjson.decode(data_str)

        table_tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data['result']['html'])

        yield table_tree

        callback_state = data['result']['stateObject']

        payload[callback_id] = html.escape(demjson.encode(callback_state))

        item_keys = callback_state['keys']
        payload['__CALLBACKPARAM'] = 'c0:KV|61;{};GB|20;12|PAGERONCLICK3|PBN;'.format(demjson.encode(item_keys))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "http://surrogateweb.co.ocean.nj.us/BluestoneWeb/Default.aspx"
    callback_id = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ASPxGridView_search'
    results = paginate(url, callback_id)
```